# "Error! Installation aborted" - dkms problem when installing or upgrading

Tags: kernel, kali-linux, drivers, realtek, dkms

When I tried to install something from GitHub or even update and upgrade the system, the error message shown below is displayed. This is on the Kali distribution. The problem is related to the Realtek driver with an Alpha wireless network adapter. I am stuck in this situation so I hope someone can help.

Here's the output when for example I try to upgrade the system (or install some software from GitHub, try to compile something etc.):

```
8814au.ko.xz:

Uninstallation
Deleting from: /lib/modules/6.6.9-amd64/updates/dkms/
Original module
No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version. depmod...... dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.6.9-amd64.
88XXau.ko.xz:

Running module version sanity check.

Module version v5.6.4.2_35491.20191025 for 88XXau.ko.xz exactly matches what is already found in kernel 6.6.9-amd64.

DKMS will not replace this module.

You may override by specifying --force.

Error! Installation aborted.

Sign command: /lib/modules/6.6.9-amd64/build/scripts/sign-file

Signing key: /var/lib/dkms/mok.key

Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/dkms/mok.pub

Building module:

Cleaning build area...

/usr/src/realtek-rtl8814au-5.8.5.1~git20231211.866a910/dkms-make.sh..........................................................................................

Signing module /var/lib/dkms/realtek-rtl8814au/5.8.5.1~git20231211.866a910/build/8814au.ko

Cleaning build area...

8814au.ko.xz: Running module version sanity check.

Original module
No original module exists within this kernel
Installation
Installing to /lib/modules/6.6.9-amd64/updates/dkms/ depmod......
88XXau.ko.xz:

Running module version sanity check.

Module version v5.6.4.2_35491.20191025 for 88XXau.ko.xz

exactly matches what is already found in kernel 6.6.9-amd64.

DKMS will not replace this module.

You may override by specifying --force.

Error! Installation aborted.

dkms autoinstall on 6.6.9-amd64/x86_64 succeeded for realtek-rtl8814au

dkms autoinstall on 6.6.9-amd64/x86_64 failed for 8812au(6) realtek- rtl88xxau(6)

Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.

Refer to previous errors for more information.

dkms: autoinstall for kernel: 6.6.9-amd64 failed!

run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11

Failed to process /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-headers-6.6.9-amd64.postinst line 11.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.6.9-amd64 (--configure):

installed linux-headers-6.6.9-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 11

Setting up libtss2-sys1:amd64 (4.0.1-7) ...

Setting up libtss2-tcti-swtpm0:amd64 (4.0.1-7) ...

Setting up libtss2-tcti-libtpms0:amd64 (4.0.1-7) ...

Setting up libtss2-tcti-device0:amd64 (4.0.1-7) ...

Setting up libtss2-tcti-spi-helper0:amd64 (4.0.1-7) ...

Setting up libtss2-tcti-cmd0:amd64 (4.0.1-7) ...

Setting up libtss2-tcti-mssim0:amd64 (4.0.1-7) ...

Setting up libtss2-esys-3.0.2-0:amd64 (4.0.1-7) ...

Setting up libopenconnect5:amd64 (9.12-1+b1) ...

Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.37-12) ... Errors were encountered while processing:

linux-headers-6.6.9-amd64 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After installing some software I try to upgrade the OS but I can't even do that because of the same problem. Can anyone help me fix this?

Here's `dkms status`:

```
8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025, 6.6.9-amd64, x86_64: built

realtek-rtl8814au/5.8.5.1~git20231211.866a910, 6.6.9-amd64, x86_64: installed
realtek-rtl88xxau/5.6.4.2~git20231117.a3e0c0b, 6.6.9-amd64, x86_64: built
```

and `uname -r` output:

```
6.6.9-amd64
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and Show us `dkms status` also `uname -r` thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Of course - I edited post and put those outputs at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under /usr/src/ look for dkms.conf for the modules

- 8812au
- realtek-rtl8814au
- realtek-rtl88xxau

under every correspondent folder is a file named

```
dkms.conf
```

Search in this files for string

```
AUTOINSTALL="yes"
```

to

```
AUTOINSTALL="no"
```

so dkms don't try to build/install them.

```
sudo dkms remove 8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025 -k 6.6.9-amd64
```

also

```
sudo dkms remove realtek-rtl88xxau/5.6.4.2~git20231117.a3e0c0b -k 6.6.9-amd64
```

and

```
sudo apt update && sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

But I can not help which module is the right one for your wlan.

Comment: this two comment doesn't works :

Comment: thanks a lot! It helps.

It's my first post on stack related forum so ... it's cool that someone can help You when You ... stack (;